# How can I make folded cloth in blender?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, cloth-simulation

I am trying to model this golf rain jacket[image: Golf Rain Jacket] and I also have to neatly fold it in the same way you would fold any shirt. How can I do this?

Comment: Probably use sculpt brush for some nice creases, retopologize, then create a basic top shape and use mesh deform on the high poly to fold it easier. I can add pictures and do a mock up if you want in an answer?

Comment: I'd really like that. Please note, im not very experienced with blender sculpting